# How to get the value of an enum using generics?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to provide the context to this question. I have seen unique solutions where people create delegates that will read/write from SharedPreferences instead of a backing field. To do this for a string, for example:

```
class SharedPrefsString(private val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return sharedPrefs.getString(property.name, "")
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(property.name, value).apply()
    }
}

var myString: String by SharedPrefsString(myPrefs)
```

However, I was hopeful that I could do the same with a generic enum, since all enums have a `valueOf(string)` method, but the below doesn't work. I put a few things I tried in the comments:

```
class SharedPrefsEnum<T : Enum<T>>(private val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        // Doesn't work, can't reference T, which makes sense. 
        // return T.valueOf(sharedPrefs.getString(property.name, ""))

        // Can't use reified type here, which makes sense.
        // return enumValueOf<T>(sharedPrefs.getString(property.name, ""))
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(property.name, value.name).apply()
    }
}

var myEnum: MyEnum by SharedPrefsEnum(myPrefs)
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: You'll probably need to grab a `Class` or `KClass`. Reified class-level generics aren't supported though, so you'll have to do it manually. There might be a better way though

Comment: @Zoe once I have a reference to the class what can I do? Figure out how to call "valueOf" with reflection?

Comment: IIRC, `valueOf` is static, so you could try using reflection to grab the method, then call that. That should be pretty straight-forward with a `Class` or `KClass`, but you could get a SecurityException. I haven't touched reflection that much, so I'm not familiar with properly avoiding those

Comment: @Zoe Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building off of your answer, you can avoid using reflection using the `enumConstants` property:

```
class SharedPrefsEnum<T : Enum<T>>(
    private val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, 
    private val clazz: Class<T>
) : ReadWriteProperty<Any, T> {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        val enumName = sharedPrefs.getString(property.name, "")
        return clazz.enumConstants.find { it.name == enumName }!!
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(property.name, value.name).apply()
    }
}
```

Then you can add a delegate easily using:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> sharedPreferences(prefs: SharedPreferences) = 
    SharedPrefsEnum(prefs, T::class.java)
```

Allowing you to assign it with:

```
private var myEnum: MyEnum by sharedPreferences(preferences)
```

You may want to make the property type nullable, however, as if your `SharedPreferences` don't contain the value this would throw an exception when accessing the value.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Will try this out shortly.

Comment: Made a small tweak to extract a val in `getValue` to avoid fetching it multiple times

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this using reflection. Thanks Zoe for pointing me in the right direction.

I had to pass in the class for the enum, too, but using that I could find `valueOf` using reflection and call it with the string I get from preferences.

```
class SharedPrefsEnum<T : Enum<T>>(private val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences, private val clazz: Class<T>) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        val prefsString = sharedPrefs.getString(property.name, "")
        val method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String::class.java)
        return method.invoke(null, prefsString) as T
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(property.name, value.name).apply()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
var lastUpdate by PersistedProperty("lastUpdate",0L)
```

and this is the implementation:

```
class PersistedProperty<T>(var prefName:String, var default: T)
{
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return value!!
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T){
        this.value=value
    }

    fun getFresh():T
    {
        value = getPreference(prefName, default)
        return value!!
    }

    var value:T? = null
        get(){
            if(field==null)
                field=getPreference(prefName, default)
            return field
        }
        set(value){
            if(value==field)
                return
            savePreference(prefName, value)
            field=value
        }

}

fun<T> savePreference(name:String, value:T,prefFile: String? = null)
{
    val sharedPreferences = App.instance.getSharedPreferences(prefFile?:App.instance.packageName+ "_preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    when(value)
    {
        is String->sharedPreferences.edit().putString(name, value).apply()
        is Int->sharedPreferences.edit().putInt(name, value).apply()
        is Long->sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(name, value).apply()
        is Float->sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat(name, value).apply()
        is Boolean->sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(name, value).apply()
        else -> throw(Exception("Not suported type"))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty similar, but unfortunately I don't think it will help for an enum.